# Booting randomly changes device nodes of HDDs, problem with munin

Tags: hard-drive, devices

I have an Ubuntu Server running 12.10 with an internal (Mainboard) SATA controller and an additional PCIe SATA controller and also external USB HDDs.

My problem is that the links to the devices (/dev/sda/sdb/sdc/sdd/sde/...) are changing randomly. I am also using munin to monitor the Ubuntu 12.10 system... when sda goes to sde all diagrams will be useless, because munin relies on NOT changing these node names and monitors /dev/sda, /dev/sdb ...

Does anyone have an idea on solving this?

Thanks and best regards Jens

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full on how-to but it might point you in the right direction.

If you migrate your fstab from using device names (sda,sdb,etc) and to using UUID's that should solve your problem of random devices changing.

http://www.softpanorama.info/Commercial_linuxes/Devices/managing_your_disks_by_uuid.shtml

This URL should help http://wiki.debian.org/Part-UUID

Hope this helps get you on the right track!

[edit]
In that case you will want to use udev rules:

http://www.rootninja.com/persistent-naming-of-a-block-device-in-linux

[/edit]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your hint, but my fstab uses UUIDs for mounting all HDs at boot time... but I think this is the cause for the problem... I need to get a consisting and lasting naming schema for /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, ... so that these device links do not change, because munin use these devices for system monitoring. When sda becomes sde after a reboot, all information before the reboot do not match... Best regards